# How to understand which of several keys was not equal in left outer join in the same query?

Tags: sql, apache-spark

Let's say I have a LEFT OUTER JOIN on several columns. And I want to provide users with reasonable error message. So I want to know which of the comparisons failed in the join.
Can this be done in a same query?

Comment: What type of SQL are you using?

Comment: Define `failed in the join` and give examples;  sample input data and expected results.

Comment: IMHO this questions is perfectly viable in an abstract sense using any variant of sql.. and I think failed in the join means: did not join :)

Comment: The `left join` fails when there is no match of *all* the keys.  I would suggest that you ask another question with sample data and desired results, with an explanation of what you are trying to really do.

Comment: @MatBailie failed in the join means the keys were not equal. So when we have join on several keys I want to know which of them did not match.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Spark SQL

Comment: You still have not clearly defined your requirements. I strongly suggest you Google 'mcve' and supply an example. I understand how outer joins work, I suspect you actually need a FULL OUTER JOIN, you may actually need a CROSS JOIN and aggregation, but until you give a minimal complete verifiable example it's just conjecture.

Answer (score 1):

Hi if i understand you correctly maybe something like this (i think once you see this you will have more relevant specific ideas for you).. basically you need to pick some things to match on and let them know other things that don't match:

```
    select
    a.one
    ,a.two
    ,a.three
    ,b.three
from
    atable as a
    left outer join anotherTable as b
        on a.one = b.one
        and a.two = b.two
        and a.three != b.three
```

You would have to create various queries for the users to check through or you could union a few together:

```
select
    a.one
    ,a.two
    ,a.three
    ,b.one
    ,b.two
    ,b.three
    ,'three differs' as "MatchStatus"
from
    atable as a
    left outer join anotherTable as b
        on a.one = b.one
        and a.two = b.two
        and a.three != b.three

UNION

select
    a.one
    ,a.two
    ,a.three
    ,b.one
    ,b.two
    ,b.three
    ,'two differs' as "MatchStatus"
from
    atable as a
    left outer join anotherTable as b
        on a.one = b.one
        and a.two != b.two
        and a.three = b.three
```

Often with real data there is a very specific priority of what you want to consider a match on..

e.g. if you have a table of bookings and attendance for training courses (both with employee number, courseID and date columns) in your situation employee number and course ID may be highly likely to be correct but sometimes people register on the wrong dates.. so then you would prioritise checking where dates don't match but the other two do.

**NOTE**: in these scenarios the sorting of the results you display to users is often the most important factor in a usable tool: a good sort will help them see what is wrong with broken links appearing together.

Comment: I'm not sure this would work. Unless all of the conditions in the join are True, there will be nothing to make a comparison in the Select.One, Two and Three are either all going to be there, or all Null using this method

Comment: Note that `"three differs" as [MatchStatus]` is invalid standard SQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name just out of curiosity what is the SQL 2011 standard way of doing this? i had a wee google but i didn't know that to search for and have no db to test against :D

Comment: @gordatron: `'three differs' as "MatchStatus"`. Double quotes are for identifiers, single quotes are for string constants. Square brackets are invalid for identifiers (unless you put them in double quotes)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Dang it! I did know that one.. i thought i was missing something bigger.. but very good shout!

Comment: @gordatron, Thanks, but the trick is to do that in one query. Making several queries might impact the performance as this is Spark SQL.

Comment: @ShamannnShamannnnot 100% sure I know what you mean... give it a try and see what you come up with, hopefully what i have suggested helps in some way.. basically you need to imagine what might not be working , combine that with business/domain knowledge and look specifically for certain issues.